# metro bundler packager terminal is missing in ubuntu 18.04 LTS while building react native app

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I'm building a react native app for android in ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I used a physical device for building my react native app. Actually it behave like the app is being build but i can't find metro bundler terminal. I have build the app by running react-native run-android command. What can i do to open metro bundler terminal? can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried npm start on another terminal ??

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge metro bundler(patching app) not run when you use physical device to run application. only run when we use emulator.
You can execute =>

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

on terminal(project directory) and use android studio to build&run your app.Otherwise when u update ur index.js file and build apk for device that update not gonna apply. so when you do some update to index.js execute that code. it ll do metro bundler(patching app) manually.

Answer (score 0):

try running **react-native start --reset-cache** in one terminal from your project directory and run **react-native run-android** from another terminal from the same directory